# Bash loop is not working — cannot find command "[0%"

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I just wrote a ping sweep script in Bash this morning, and guess what: it's not working. Can you please check what it is that I'm missing.

Here's the script:

```
for i in `seq 1 255`
do
    if ["$(ping -c1 -W1 -n 192.168.1.$i | grep '%' | cut -d',' -f3 | cut -d' ' -f2)" -eq "0%"]
    then echo "Host live"
    else echo "Host down"
    fi
done
```

And here's the error:

```
bash: [0%: command not found
Host down
bash: [100%: command not found
Host down
```

My purpose is to make a ping sweep program which scans the range 192.168.1.1-255 and it notifies the host's status. I know about nmap but just wanted to learn skills in Bash so I made this one. Please try to tell what the error meant. I mean to what command it's referring "command not found"?

Comment: Please — 'one-liner' is a term of abuse, not praise.  Format your code so it can be read, even if Bash's history mechanism abuses your efforts by flattening your code by default.

Comment: What nested loops?  You only have one loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sir, actually I just copy-pasted the contents from bash to here as I was running one liner in bash. Will take care in future. Thank you.

Comment: My mistake @BenVoigt, I counted conditional statement as loop :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Primary diagnosis

The `[` command needs a space after its name, just like the `rm` command needs a space after its name and the `ls` command does, and …  The `[` command also requires its last argument to be `]`, spelled thus, so there needs to be a space before that, too.

You have:

```
if ["$(ping -c1 -W1 -n 192.168.1.$i | grep '%' | cut -d',' -f3 | cut -d' ' -f2)" -eq "0%"]
```

At minimum, you need:

```
if [ "$(ping -c1 -W1 -n 192.168.1.$i | grep '%' | cut -d',' -f3 | cut -d' ' -f2)" -eq "0%" ]
```

---

#### Secondary issues

Note that 'at minimum' means, amongst other things, that I've not spent time analyzing why you are executing the complex sequence of 4 commands in the test condition, or looked for ways to cut that down to two (using `grep` and `cut` twice suggests that `sed` or a more powerful tool would be better).  I griped about the formatting in the original version of the question, where the loop (it isn't a nested loop, incidentally — or it isn't in the code shown) was all on one line thanks to Bash flattening it in history.  My version of the code would have far fewer semicolons in it, for example.  The `-eq` operator in `[` is for testing the equality of numbers (the converse convention applies in Perl, where `eq` is for testing strings and `==` tests numbers).  Note that POSIX standard `[` (aka `test`) does not support `==` as a synonym for `=`, though Bash does.  It isn't entirely clear that `"0%"` is OK as an argument for numeric comparison.  Many programs would not object — the zero can be converted and the residue doesn't matter; others might decide legitimately to complain that the whole string could not be converted, so it is erroneous.  Careful code wouldn't risk the disconnect.

See [Steven Penny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002260/steven-penny)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31601824/15168) for a more thorough rewrite of the code.  My answer remains a valid diagnosis of the immediate problem of not being able to find commands named `[0%` and `[100%`.

Comment: Yes I am, but I just copy-pasted the code from terminal to here so... Will take care in future.

Comment: Well, @JonathanLeffler sir, I corrected the mistake. But these errors are coming:
`bash: [: 0%: integer expression expected
Host down
bash: [: 100%: integer expression expected
Host down
bash: [: 100%: integer expression expected
Host down`
What to do?

Comment: Aah fixed it. `-eq` had to be replaced with `==`. That's it. But I wonder, why is this necessary when both have same meanings in bash.

Comment: @Adarsh they dont. `-eq` is arithmetic comparison

Comment: Oh, okay got that. Thanks @StevenPenny. So that was the reason of the error "integer expression expected" because I was comparing a string with it. Hmm...

Answer (score 5):

The `ping` command returns error code if there was any problem, so you do not need to parse the output:

```
for i in {1..255}
do
  if ping -c1 -W1 -n "192.168.1.$i"
  then
    echo 'Host live'
  else
    echo 'Host down'
  fi
done
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. But actually I'm trying to learn combination of different commands that's why used all those.

Comment: I didn't dissect the inside of the code; I simply identified the problems with the syntax.  (I had to go fetch my daughter from a practice immediately after answering, too.)  What you've done is a much more serious (and very sensible) rewrite of the code.